# Exactly same logic, 1st code storing data as Map<String, Boolean> and 2nd as Map<Integer, Boolean>. 1st runs fine. 2nd gives StackOverflow error. Why?

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm solving a [problem from Interviewbit](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/word-break/) where the exact same code logic is giving 2 different outcomes. First code is storing data as `Map<String, Boolean>`, another code is storing it as `Map<Integer, Boolean>`. First one runs successfully, but the second code gives `StackOverflow` error. How is this possible?

First code is as follows:

```
private boolean f1(String s, int start, Set<String> dict, Map<String, Boolean> map){
    if(start == s.length()) return true;
    String query = s.substring(start);
    if(map.containsKey(query)) return map.get(query);
    for(int i=1; i<=query.length(); i++){
        String word = query.substring(0,i);
        if(dict.contains(word)){
            if(f1(s, start+i, dict, map)){
                map.put(query, true);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    map.put(query, false);
    return false;
}
```

Above code runs fine and is successfully accepted without any errors.

However, if I simply change the code a little bit, by storing the data as `Map<Integer, Boolean>`, it throws StackOverflow error. Here is that code:

```
private boolean f2(String s, int start, Set<String> dict, Map<Integer, Boolean> map){
    if(start == s.length()) return true;
    String query = s.substring(start);
    if(map.containsKey(start)) return map.get(start);
    for(int i=1; i<=query.length(); i++){
        String word = query.substring(0,i);
        if(dict.contains(word)){
            if(f2(s, start+i, dict, map)){
                map.put(start, true);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    map.put(start, false);
    return false;
}
```

How is it possible that the exact same logic, first code (using `Map<String, Boolean>`) is working, but, second code (using `Map<Integer, Boolean>`) is throwing `StackOverflow` error?

I am also adding the main function that is calling the above function `f`, in case that helps.

```
public int wordBreak(String A, String[] B) {
    // A is the unbroken word, eg. "myinterviewtrainer", and B is the list of words, eg. ["trainer", "my", "interview"]
    int n = A.length();
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(B));
    Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
    // Map<Integer, Boolean> map = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
    return (f1(A, 0, set, map) ? 1 : 0);
    // return (f2(A, 0, set, map) ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your input for both the cases

Comment: I agree. The inputs would have helped tremendously. Unfortunately, the 2nd code is throwing that error only when it's "Submit"-ed there in Interviewbit, and it's not mentioning for which testcase it is happening.

Comment: What's important to note here, is that for the exact same input, first code is working, second is throwing StackOverflow error.

Comment: Did you try using a debugger to see what is actually going on when the exception is being thrown?

Comment: That's some weird problem... so you return `true` if the given suffix of the string contains a substring found in `dict` at index `i` *and* if you take that suffix starting at `i` you have the same property... so it's true if a suffix always contains a substring found in `dict` in the remainder... but then if the string does not end with a substring in `dict` the result will be false. However if the substring does end with a substring in dict the result is true for all indixes before that ending substring... in other words you could just check the ending of `s` and avoid that weird recursion

Comment: @SanjibanBairagya I actually tried these 2 methods, and both of them return 1, no Stackoverflow (Java 1.8)

Comment: Hi @Bentaye do you mean you tried them in interviewbit itself, or in your local machine?
The issue is happening for not all testcases.

Comment: @SanjibanBairagya I mean on my machine, I don't know how interviewbit  works

Comment: @SanjibanBairagya that's why one would write unit tests while developing code :-)

Comment: I tested my code in my local using dozens of test cases, and I'm pretty sure I covered all of the corner cases, and my code works fine. Not sure why in InterviewBit it's still throwing StackOverflow for function f2.
Problem is IB doesn't show testcase for which the error is thrown, and also, if I try to debug using try-catch, it doesn't print it because the stacktrace fills up the word limit.

Comment: If someone can get some hints by reading through the code, that would be super-helpful. Btw, the error might also be thrown simply because of some internal issues with Interviewbit as well, but still, that's not for sure. It could be because of some one particular testcase as well which I might be missing to identify.

Comment: @SanjibanBairagya which runtime are you using? I tried to copy paste your code using f2 at https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/word-break/ and it passes the tests for both java 8, java 8 with array support and java 7...

Comment: Hi @Niccolò thanks for trying that out and confirming. So, if my code is indeed able to be submitted successfully in IB, then it looks like it must have been some internal technical issues why I was (and still am) getting that error. Cool then, I'll move on now! :)